# Contar total registros iguales en dos tablas diferentes con Group By entre 3 tablas relaccionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Eh tratado de realizar un query que me extraiga la informacion de una tabla donde se almacenan cierta informacion

> Esta tabla contiene comentarios

Adicionalmente tengo otras dos tablas que estan relaccionadas a esta, tales son la tabla de me gusta y tabla de repuesta de los comentarios, lo que quiero y eh intentado hacer es poder sacar la cantidad de respuestas y me gusta que tienen cada comentario, lo eh intentado realizar con el siguiente query

Esquema de Tablas y query

```
Tabla - comentarios
id_comentarios int(11)
comentarios text

Tabla - respuestas
id_respuestas int(11)
id_comentarios int(11)
respuesta text

Tabla - Me_gusta
id_megusta int(11)
id_comentarios int(11)
id_user_likes int(11)
```

La tabla comentarios esta relaccionada con la tabla Me_guta y la tabla respuestas

El query con el que intento sacar la informacion que deseo es este

```
SELECT com.id_comentarios as id_comentario, com.comentarios as comentarios, 
COUNT(lk.id_comentarios) AS count_megusta, COUNT(res.id_comentarios) as count_respuestas
FROM comentarios com 
LEFT JOIN l_like_foro as lk ON com.id_comentarios = lk.id_comentarios
LEFT JOIN respuestas as res ON res.id_comentarios = com.id_comentarios 
WHERE com.id_foro = 1 GROUP BY com.id_comentarios,lk.id_comentarios HAVING COUNT(lk.id_comentarios) >= 0
```

Cuando ejecuto este query las respuestas de cada comentario las agrupa bien, con las cantidades que les corresponde, pero cuando el query va agrupar y hacer el count a los registros de me gusta no corresponden a la cantidad

Comment: No tienes que usar `id_comentarios` dos veces al agrupar, basta con que dejes solamente la columna de la tabla principal: `GROUP BY com.id_comentarios`  Así debería funcionar, eso suponiendo que tienes los datos bien almacenados. Y.. el  `HAVING` no sé lo que pinta ahí. También, en este tipo de consultas la columna `comentarios` no sirve de nada... ¿quieres el texto de lo comentarios?  si es así, debes traerlos también agrupados, usando `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_comentarios AS id,
    count(id_comentarios) AS cant,
    'respuesta' AS dato
    FROM respuestas
    GROUP BY id_comentarios

UNION
SELECT id_comentarios AS id,
    count(id_comentarios) AS cant,
    'me_gusta' AS dato
    FROM Me_gusta
    GROUP BY id_comentarios

ORDER BY id_comentarios;
```

Utilizando este query obtienes 2 lineas por cada comentario, por ejemplo el comentario `1` tiene 5 respuestas y 3 me gustas:

```
--------------------------
| id | cant | dato       |
--------------------------
| 1  |  5   | comentario |
--------------------------
| 1  |  3   | me_gusta   |
--------------------------
```